# Trouble assigning dataframe's column name dynamically

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

there! It seemed simple in my head, but now I am stucked trying to generate df's dynamically by reading json's from a folder. I just want to save the info in dataframes iteratively called chat1, chat2, and so on. All dataframes have 2 columns: (1) username and (2) one that it is named after the very df: chat1 has a column 'chat1', 'chat2' has a column chat2, etc.

This is my code:

```
directory = '/content/drive/My Drive/chatsI'
i=1
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    f = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        data = json.load(open(f))
        print('Working on file', i)
        df = pd.json_normalize(data["comments"])
        users = df['commenter.display_name'].value_counts()
        users= users.index.tolist()
        globals()[f"chat{i}"] = pd.DataFrame (users, columns = ['user_name'])
        globals()[f"chat{i}"][globals()[f"chat{i}"]] = '1'
        i=i+1
```

But for some reason the `globals()[f"chat{i}"][globals()[f"chat{i}"]] = '1'` thows a TypeError: Must pass DataFrame or 2-d ndarray with boolean values only.

I know it is a popular topic, but ironically I haven't been able to find a proper answer for that. I would very helpful if someone could give me a hint on what could be wrong with that line of code. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Try looking at [How to rename columns in Pandas Dataframe](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-rename-columns-in-pandas-dataframe/?adlt=strict&toWww=1&redig=5151FE9A6BDA4FCDAF0A8B382CDDD4EB).

Comment: Hi, thanks. I've tryed renaming with globals()[f"chat{i}"]['column1'] = '1'
        globals()[f"chat{i}"].rename(columns = {'column1': globals()[f"chat{i}"]}, inplace = True), but it still fails because it creates recursion

Answer (score 0):

PD: fixed it myself. It just needed a local dynamic variable:

```
directory = '/content/drive/My Drive/chatsI'
i=1
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    f = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        data = json.load(open(f))
        print('Working on file', i)
        df = pd.json_normalize(data["comments"])
        users = df['commenter.display_name'].value_counts()
        users= users.index.tolist()
        globals()[f"chat{i}"] = pd.DataFrame (users, columns = ['user_name'])
        a = 'chat' + str(i)
        globals()[f"chat{i}"][a] = '1'
        i=i+1
```